# Ember-CLI app deployed to heroku with environment=production loses global app namespace

Tags: heroku, ember.js, ember-cli, environment

My app name is App and I have access to the App namespace when environment=developing. Only problem is that issues arise when I use the production version by running (ember server --environment=production, then I no longer have access to the App namespace as it is undefined.

```
Error while processing route: coming-soon App is not defined ReferenceError: App is not defined
```

Is this a security measure ember-cli takes? How can I override this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ember-cli comes with the addon [ember-export-application-global](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-export-application-global).
By default it doesn't export the app name to the global scope in production environment.
You can override this behavior by adding in `config/environment.js` :

```js
//config/environment.js
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    //...
    //...
    exportApplicationGlobal: true
      //...
      //...
  }

  //...
  //...
};
```